# Spring JPA EntityManager startup appears to be slow

Tags: spring, jpa

```
2015-10-20 09:34:01 DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.ValidationXmlParser,98 - No META-INF/validation.xml found. Using annotation based configuration only.
2015-10-20 09:35:02 INFO  org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean,339 - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

Why is it taking a full minute between these steps?  Is there another level of logging I can turn on that might provide more info?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring but with your `EntityManagerFactory` doing things. Apparently you have a lot of entities or are scanning every package for entities and all entities in turn are scanned for annotations again. Also hibernate is trying to acquire a connection to validate your entities against the schema (or vice-versa depends on how you look at it).

Comment: Which datasource are you using? It may due to the your database connection.

Comment: I'm using Hibernate - I have the logging set to debug; how can I determine where the performance is flagging?

Comment: Well, I did set `@EntityScan(basePackages = "etc.model")` and I'm testing with a local SqlExpress as well as HSql.